# Is a element on SVG line animatable

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have this 8-shaped loop as an SVG image. I am interested in animating a white 50px length element animating along the 8-loop infinitely.

I understand that SVG animations are animatable to draw out but how could this element follow the line of the SVG inifitely and is this possible to achieve or not? Is this even reasonable to achieve with CSS?

Here's the SVG path the element should follow:
[image]

Here's a view of the SVG white element that should animate and loop across the line. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have understood the question correctly.

Yes, it's possible.

The following lines of code can be used as a basis. I have only tested in Chrome, perhaps i write it on my laptop in the train...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SVG 001</title>
  <style>
    body{font-family:"Calibri", sans-serif;}
    svg{border:1px solid #eee;}
    
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Offset Dasharray</h1>
   <svg id ="mySVG" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
   <path id="myPath" d="M 50 50 q 200 800 400 0" stroke="#ccc"
    stroke-width="10" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <br>
  <button onclick="dashAni(myPath, 50, 1500)">start</button>
  <script>
    var dashAni = function(path, length, duration){
      var dashPath = path.cloneNode(true);
      mySVG.appendChild(dashPath);
      var pathLen=path.getTotalLength();  
      var aktPos=0
      var sumSteps = duration / (1000/60) // 60 pics per second
      var step=0;
      var pathAnim;
      dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + (pathLen - length));
      dashPath.setAttribute('stroke', "red");
      dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

      var anim=function(){
         aktPos = pathLen/sumSteps*step*-1;
          //aktLen = easeInOutQuad(step/sumSteps)*len;
         dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + pathLen);
         dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

         if (step <= (sumSteps)){
          step++;
          pathAnim = setTimeout(anim, 1000/60) //1000/60 pics/second
          } else {
            mySVG.removeChild(dashPath);
            clearTimeout(pathAnim);
          }
      }
     anim();
    }
    dashAni(myPath, 50, 1500);
  </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You answer guides me in the right direction. Although I am still unable to achieve the white animated line along the svg: https://jsfiddle.net/yrj7htoy/2/ . Could you please advise this code?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have non continious path. When you use more than one 'm' the path is broken...